# Diccionarios dentro de un diccionario

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Tengo un diccionario con listas:

```
d1 = {
  'frutas': {
     ' manzanas': [' verdes', ' 7', ' rojas', ' 5'],
      'uvas': [' negras', ' 5', ' verdes', ' 3']
   },
   ' verduras': {
      'papa': ['negras', ' 50', ' blancas', ' 20'],
      'cebolla': [' blancas', ' 30']
   },
   'cereales': {
      ' arroz': [' fino',' 600', ' largo', ' 800']
   }
}
```

Quisiera poder mostrar con una función cada una de las keys con sus respectivas listas, pero sin mostrar el contenido de la lista.
Así:

```
frutas : manzanas, uvas
verduras : papa, cebolla
cereales : arroz
```

**Detalle: d1 esta cargado desde un archivo.txt en mi pc. La funcion me deberia servir para cualquier otro dX que cargue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que recuperas los datos de un archivo, antes lo conviertes a diccionario para poder manipularlo, el modulo ast:

```
def leer():
   archivo= open( ruta_DE_TU_aRChivo, 'r')
   texto= archivo.read()
   archivo.close()
   #convertir a diccionario
   import ast
   d1= ast.literal_eval( texto)

   # Los diccionarios tienen estos metodos: keys() para obtener las claves, y values():

   for item in d1.keys():

      temp= ','.join(  d1[item].keys()  )
      print(item,":",   temp)
```

Answer (score 4):

Los diccionarios python tienen un par de métodos que pueden serte útiles en este caso. `diccionario.keys()` te da una lista con todas las claves del diccionario. `diccionario.items()` te da otra lista con parejas (clave, valor).

Usando ambas cosas y el método `str.join()` para concatenar varios elementos de una lista y formar con ellos una cadena, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
for clave, valor in d1.items():
  # La clave sería por ejemplo "frutas", el valor sería en este caso 
  # otro diccionario. Con `valor.keys()` sacamos la lista
  # de claves de este otro diccionario, que serían los nombres de las frutas
  elementos = ", ".join(valor.keys())
  print(clave, ":", elementos)
```

```
frutas :  manzanas, uvas
verduras : papa, cebolla
cereales :  arroz
```